# What is "!!" command shown in top result

Tags: amazon-ec2, htop

I run two drupal 8 websites on an amazon ec2 instance. They are portfolio sites. below is server details.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-0-0-xx ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-xx-0-0-xx 4.4.15-25.57.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 27 22:37:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[ec2-user@ip-xx-0-0-xx ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       59G   15G   45G  25% /
devtmpfs        238M   56K  238M   1% /dev
tmpfs           246M     0  246M   0% /dev/shm

[ec2-user@ip-xx-0-0-xx ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           491        301        189         59         28        107
-/+ buffers/cache:        165        325
Swap:        10239          8      10231
```

The websites do not have much visitors (so not much load i guess). but server goes down once a month or so. I dont know what is causing the server to go down. 
Below is result of htop command [image: screenshot]

There is this process started by apache called **!!** .Sometimes it uses upto 99% of CPU.

Comment: Add the output of `sudo ls -l /proc/4943/exe` to the post, please. (Or use any PID of `!!` instead of `4943`).

Comment: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231/49745)

Comment: @MichaelHomer does that mean my server is comprimised??

Comment: @muru sorry iam not getting any output. The server is damn slow

Comment: @muru
 `lrwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache 0 Jun 20 05:05 /proc/3214/exe -> /tmp/K252Pei5L
`

Comment: Shut it dowm ! And restore a backup quickly !

Comment: Shut it down, and ***slowly** consider* restoring a backup.